# Can a function be differentiable if the limit does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm trying to find if the function is differentiable at $x=1$. Upon solving, the limit does not exist. But when I tried to solve for the limit of $f '(1)$, I both got $3\over2$, so $f '(1)$ exists. So, is the function differentiable at $x=1$?
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\ln(x^2+x) & x ≤ 1 \\
3\sqrt x & x > 1 \\
\end{cases}$$

**I.** $$ f(1) = \ln (1^2 +1) = \ln(2)$$
**II.** $$\lim_{x\to1^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\to1^-} \ln(x^2+x) = \ln(1^2+1) = \ln(2)$$
$$\lim_{x\to1^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to1^+} 3 \sqrt x= 3\sqrt1 = 3 $$
$$\lim_{x\to1^-} f(x) ≠ \lim_{x\to1^+} f(x) $$
Thus the $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ does not exist.

$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x} & x < 1 \\
\frac{3}{2\sqrt x} & x > 1 \\
\end{cases}$$

**a)** $$ f'_+(1) = \lim_{x\to1^+}f'(x )=  \lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{3}{2\sqrt x} = \frac{3}{2\sqrt1} = \frac{3}{2}$$
**b)**$$ f'_-(1) = \lim_{x\to1^-}f'(x)=  \lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{2x+1}{x^2+ x} = \frac{2 + 1}{1+1} = \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: It is easier for people to help you if you show us what you have done.

Comment: It's in the pic.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992

Comment: From our [formatting and writing guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992): "Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have not shown that $f'(1)$ exists.  You have shown that
$$
\lim_{x\to1^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x\to1^-} f'(x),
$$
but this does not imply that $f'(1)$ exists, or is equal to this limit.

To show that $f'(1)$ exists, you would have to show that the limit
$$
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h}
$$
exists.  But it is not too hard to see that this limit does not exist as $h \to 0^+$, as the numerator approaches $3 - \ln 2 \neq 0$ in this limit while the denominator will approach zero.

In general, a function must be continuous at any point at which it is differentiable (though the converse is of course not true.)

Comment: Ooh, I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you've got a typo in the next-to-last paragraph: the first "denominator" should be "numerator", right?

Comment: @DavidZ:  Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

A simple example: let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & x ≤ 0 \\
1 & x > 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

The left and right limits of $f'$ at $x=0$ both exist and are equal to the same value (namely, zero), but that doesn't mean that $f'(0)$ exists.

Answer (score 4):

[Differentiability of real functions of one variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) implies continuity of the function in that point, since you verify the function is not continuous neither is differentiable